# how to output different types of data in php?

Tags: php

This is how my table is shown.

[image]

The code for the creation and returning of the table:
i would like to test the value of the sport ID value. if it is 1, return football. if it is 2 return Tennis and if it is 3 return swimming. And if the away column is TRUE i want it to output Away, else output HOME.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE fixtureDetails
(
fixtureID INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
opponent VARCHARD(30) NOT NULL,
date DATE
away BOOLEAN,
sportID INT
refereeID INT,
PRIMARY KEY (fixtureID),
FOREIGN KEY (sportID) REFERENCES sport(sportID),
FOREIGN KEY (refereeID) REFERENCES referee(refereeID)
)";

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM fixtureDetails";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>fixtureID</th>";
                echo "<th>opponent</th>";
                echo "<th>date</th>";
                echo "<th>away</th>";
                echo "<th>sportID</th>";
                echo "<th>refereeID</th>";
            echo"</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['fixtureID'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['opponent'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['away'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sportID'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['refereeID'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo "No records matching your query found.";
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR: could not execute $sql1. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: You should be thinking about adding a table to contain the `1=football.2=Tennis and 3=swimming

Comment: And another to do the same thing for `Home and Away`

Comment: I do have that table. it is called sport with the columns sportID and name

Comment: @RiggsFolly I believe he already does have another table for the `Sport` via: `FOREIGN KEY (sportID) REFERENCES sport(sportID)` in his table create script.

Comment: @Siyual Ah yes, missed that :~( thanks

Comment: @FaayoBedrudin Does this *have* to be done in PHP?  This would be much easier in SQL.

Comment: you have to use joint queries http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @Siyual which part exactly

Comment: @FaayoBedrudin See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<td>" . $row['fixtureID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['opponent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
if($row['away'])
  echo "<td>Away</td>";
else
  echo "<td>Home</td>";

switch($row['sportID']){
   case 1: echo "<td>Football</td>";
       break;
   case 2: echo "<td>Tennis</td>";
       break;
   case 3: echo "<td>Swimming</td>";
       break;
   default: echo "Error!";
 }
echo "<td>" . $row['refereeID'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the structure of the `Sport` table, so I'm assuming there is a column in that table named `Name`.  You can change this part to reflect your actual table.

I wouldn't use PHP to retrieve those values if they're already in the database (as hinted by the following in your `CREATE` statement):

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (sportID) REFERENCES sport(sportID),
```

Instead of the `SELECT * FROM fixtureDetails;` query you're using, I would use the following query instead:

```sql
Select  F.FixtureId,
        F.Opponent,
        F.Date,
        Case When F.Away = 1 Then 'Away' Else 'Home' End As Away,
        S.Name As Sport,    -- Change S.Name to the actual column in Sport.
        F.RefereeId
From    FixtureDetails  F
Join    Sport           S   On  S.SportId = F.SportId
```

Comment: That saves me writing it up

Answer (score 0):

Please check it:

```
echo "<td>" . (isset($row['away']) && $row['away']) ? 'AWAY' : 'HOME' . "</td>";
```